# Python: why simplejson dumping doesn't escape \t?

Tags: python, simplejson

I found that simplejson module doesn't escape `\t`.

So dictionary `{'a': 'test  1'}` (there is tabulation between `test` and `1`) when dumps through simplejson function returns string `'{"a": "test   1"}'` with `\t` in it.

But the problem is that `jQuery.parseJSON()` function returns an error if there is tabulation in parsed string:

> **SyntaxError**: Unexpected token

How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there something I'm missing.  Why not just use the `json` module that comes with Python rather than `simplejson`?

Comment: @Endophage -- probably python version.  That's only in 2.6 or later.  Relevant for AppEngine.

Comment: @Endophage: the same situation. I've checked right now...

Comment: @Matt ah, wasn't aware, only used 2.7 and 3

Answer (score 1):

Which `simplejson` function are you using? This looks right to me:

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> simplejson.dumps({'a': 'test\t1'})
'{"a": "test\\t1"}'
```

Comment: my fault - my editor automatically replaces tabulation with four spaces... Sorry

Comment: It can often make more sense to use `\t` in Python strings for clarity than a literal tab.